# ReactJS conflict in version and dependencies causing "Stateless function components cannot have refs"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This problem has been bogging me down since the last 4 days. I am using React 15.6.1 (although npm pulls in 15.6.2 by default). Heres a partial list of my package.json file:

```
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
"react-datepicker": "^0.55.0",
"react-document-meta": "^2.1.2",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-dotdotdot": "^1.1.0",
"react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
"react-native-cards-slider": "^0.1.2",
"react-redux": "^4.4.7",
"react-redux-toastr": "^7.1.4",
"react-router": "^2.4.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.4"
```

I get a "Stateless function components cannot have refs" in the index file. The error points to this location:

(anonymous function)
src/index.js:15

```
  12 | const store = configure();
  13 | 
  14 | 
> 15 | ReactDOM.render(
  16 |   <Provider store={store}>
  17 |     <App />
  18 |   </Provider>,
```

A more detailed with all stack expanded error display is given below:

```
Stateless function components cannot have refs.
▼ 17 stack frames were expanded.
invariant
node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42
attachRef
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:845
addComponentAsRefTo
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactOwner.js:69
attachRef
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactRef.js:23
ReactRef.attachRefs
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactRef.js:42
attachRefs
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconciler.js:23
notifyAll
node_modules/react-dom/lib/CallbackQueue.js:76
close
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80
closeAll
node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:209
perform
node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:156
batchedMountComponentIntoNode
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:126
perform
node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:143
batchedUpdates
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdates.js:97
_renderNewRootComponent
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:319
_renderSubtreeIntoContainer
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:401
render
node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:422
▲ 17 stack frames were expanded.
(anonymous function)
src/index.js:15

  12 | const store = configure();
  13 | 
  14 | 
> 15 | ReactDOM.render(
  16 |   <Provider store={store}>
  17 |     <App />
  18 |   </Provider>,

View compiled
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
```

I am new to ReactJS and am badly stuck with this. A lot of people I asked have been telling me that this is a version issue but I tried both downgrading and upgrading but none worked. I also got a recommendation to use this section of code but I don't have the faintest clue where to put or how to use it:

```
function Component = () => {
  let $ref;

  return (
    <InnerComponent ref={(ref) => { $ref = ref; }} />
  );
};
```

Also incase its required here is my src/index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configure from './store/configureStore';
import App from './containers/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './assets/styles/components.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

const store = configure();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Also, this is my src/containers/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import MainLayout from './Layout/Mainlayout';
import Home from './home/Home';
import Login from './login/Login';
import SignUp from './login/SignUp';
import Experience from './experience/';
import About from './about/About';
import Contact from './contact/Contact';
import Terms from './terms/Terms';
import EventDetail from './eventdetail/';
import Listing from './Listing/Listing';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainLayout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/experience/:id" component={Experience}/>
            <Route path="/rovelogues/:slug" component={Listing}/>
            {/* <Route path="/events" component={Events}/> */}
            <Route path="/events/:id" component={EventDetail}/>
            <Route path="/rovelogues-by-pro" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
            <Route path="/terms" component={Terms}/>
          </Route>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help or guidance pointing out what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how does your App component look like?

Comment: @kunukn please take a look at the edit above. Thanks

Comment: You can try to restrict the versions installed from package.json. Delete/rename/move your node_modules folder and install again. I would suggest to specify exact known working version for your case. I would specifically focus on react, react-rounter, react-router-dom, redux and react-router-redux.  `"react": "15.6.1"` `"react-redux": "4.4.7"`etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Yarn instead of Npm. https://yarnpkg.com/en/

once it's installed test that it's recognized in your console with

```
yarn --version
```

then in your project folder delete the `node_modules` folder then run

```
yarn
```

there's a good chance yarn will know what versions go well together and you'll stop having that issue.